# Limit of $f^{-1}(f(x))$ as $f(x)$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inverse-function

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous, real-valued, one-to-one function on some domain $(a,b)$ which diverges at one end of the domain (say $b$). As $f$ is one-to-one I expect to be able to define a inverse function $f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ for $x$ in the domain of $f$.

Is the limit
$$ \lim_{x\to b} f^{-1}(f(x)) \,,$$
well defined (and presumably equal to $b$), and if so is there a general procedure for evaluating
$$ \lim_{x\to b} f^{-1}(c \, f(x)) \,,$$
for some constant $c$?

---

I have in mind $$\lim_{x\to \pi/2} \arctan( c \, \tan(x) )$$
in particular if there is some further condition that $f$ must meet to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f:(a,b)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and injective then it must be monotone. If $f$ 'diverges' near $b$ it must be unbounded near $b$; $+\infty$ if $f$ is increasing and $-\infty$ if $f$ is decreasing. We assume the first case for simplicity, but the other case can be treated in much the same manner.

Since $f$ is injective, it admits an inverse $f^{-1}:\text{Im}(f)\longrightarrow (a,b)$. It will also be monotone: because $f$ is continuous, it maps connected sets to connected sets, so $\text{Im}(f)\subset \mathbb{R}$ will also be an interval. We have then that $f^{-1}(x)$ approaches $b$ as $x\to +\infty$.

The limit $\lim_{x\to b}f^{-1}(f(x))$ clearly always exists because it is simply $\lim_{x\to b} x$. When $c>0$, $\lim_{x \to b}f(x)=\lim_{x \to b}c\cdot f(x)=+\infty$, so $\lim_{x\to b}f^{-1}(c\cdot f(x))=b$.

However, for $c\leq 0$ the limit may not be defined.

Comment: This is what I thought (though obviously phrased in a more precise manner---I'm a physicist and speak math haltingly and with an accent), but it's been sitting in the back of my mind bothering me. Something in my subconscience keeps shouting "L'Hopital! L'Hopital!" even though a direct application doesn't make any sense at all.